# How can i print .txt with .zpl code inside in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, printing, zebra-printers, zpl

Actually i need to print a .txt file, inside the .txt i have a mask for printers Zebra (.zpl instructions).
When i send to print the document, the printer, printing the code and not the mask.
What can i do?

Visual Studio Community 2019
Zebra ZT410 by USB port

```
Private Sub ImprimirQR_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ImprimirQR.Click
   'prueba.Text = "^XA\" + vbCrLf + "^FO100,100" + vbCrLf + "^A0, 35,35^FDCODIGO QR^FS" + vbCrLf + "^FO100,200^BQ,2,10" + vbCrLf + "^FDHM,A" + CadenaQR + "^FS" + vbCrLf + "^XZ"
    'Try
    '    ZPrinter.PrintLabel(1, prueba.Text)
    'Catch ex As Exception
    '    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + vbCrLf + ex.ToString)
    'End Try
```

end sub

Comment: Unrelated, but use & instead of + when working with strings.

Comment: Do you mean the printer is printing the actual ZPL code and not what the code is supposed to render?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer to the same question. [Send String to printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53330880/sending-raw-text-to-printer-via-usb/53371049#53371049)

Also if you intend to send a file, use this command instead

```
RAWPOSPrinter.SendFileToPrinter("<NAME OF PRINTER AS IT APPEARS IN DEVICES AND PRINTERS>", "<FILE NAME OF FILE THAT CONTAINS ZEBRA COMMANDS>")
```