# Send Command to Zebra Label Printer

Tags: vb.net, printing, label, zebra-printers, epl

I need to send the following command to a Zebra Label Printer:

`q270`

everything I can find online tends to be in C# and I'm working in VB.Net

I was hoping this would be as simple as an example I found online

which basically was

```
Dim sb As StringBuilder
sb.AppendLine("q270")

RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(printername, sb.tostring())
```

but RawPrinterHelper appears to be a class I don't have, every example if this I can find is in C#. They also appear to be for sending a much more complex string of text to the printer. So I am getting a little lost in it all.

Can anyone assist in sending the single `q270` command to the printer?

The printer is a Zebra LP2844. It prints these little sticky labels. The command I'm sending is a EPL command.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about my answer here: [Sending raw text to printer via USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53330880/sending-raw-text-to-printer-via-usb/53371049#53371049)

Comment: RawPrinterHelper seems to be a support helper class used in some Microsoft printing related documentation. Though quick search for official version just returns bunch of pages with broken links. There are several copies and variations of it around with most just wrapper for winspool API calls.

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b that looks simple to use, much simpler then other examples i had seen. i will give it a go. 

I did work out tho, that the command that was needed to sent to the printer can be set in the printers Custom Commands. after it receives a "PAGE" to print you can then tell it that and the end of the page to add the command. 

But i would still like to get a programmatic version of if working so that if the software is deployed and no one bothers to update the settings of the printer the code will at least handle the setting for them.

Comment: @AndyAndromeda it's up to your app to generate the commands necessary for the printer to function correctly. All that class does is pass the commands to the Zebra printer in raw text form.

Comment: Yes I understand that. And I know what the command is that I need to send. It's the "q270" as it sets the size of the label.